# Is there any handwavy argument that shows that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx} dk = 2\pi \delta(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

It should not be a good argument but rather a short one and one that convinces a physicist ( so no need for mathematical rigor ) that shows that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx} dk = 2\pi \delta(x)$ holds? It should only refer to basic calculus (especially no fourier transform ) since I am supposed to give a proof of a related relationship about fourier transforms on a physics homework sheet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x) & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx} \mathrm{d}k\\
\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx} \mathrm{d}k \mathrm{d}x & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon e^{-ikx} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}k \\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \cos(kx) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}k \\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin(k\epsilon)}{k} \, \mathrm{d}k \\
& = 2\pi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Hope that was short enough.

Comment: I'd like to make this a tad more rigorous by pointing out that the $x$-integral ought to be from $a+\epsilon$ to $a-\epsilon$ so that when you take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the final integral is $2\pi$ _exactly when_ $a=0$ and is $0$ everywhere else (which is the definition of the delta function). Also, we didn't need to leave off the imaginary part integral since it goes to zero everywhere.

Comment: I agree to your first comment. And I left the imaginary part because it is an odd function.

Comment: i don't see a clear connection between the last 2 steps of derivation.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{-a}^{a} e^{-ikx} dk =   \frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ix} |^{+a}_{-a}= i\frac{e^{-iax}-e^{iax}}{x}   $$

$$e^{-iax}-e^{iax}=-2i \sin {(ax)}   $$

$$\int_{-a}^{a} e^{-ikx} dk =   i\frac{e^{-iax}-e^{iax}}{x}   =  i\frac{-2i \sin {ax}}{x}   =2\frac{\sin {ax}}{x} = f_a(x) $$

You need to find the limit. Lets define $\lim\limits_{ a\to \infty  }  f_a(x) = 2\pi \delta(x)$

$$\lim\limits_{ a\to \infty  } \int_{-a}^{+a} e^{-ikx} dk = \lim\limits_{ a\to \infty  } 2\frac{\sin {ax}}{x}= 2\pi \delta(x) $$

we can check some graphs for some $a$ values

$a=100$
[image]

$a=10^{100}$
[image]

Finally If $ a\to \infty $ then we get the function $2\pi \delta(x)$ below.

The function  for $x\neq0 $

$2\pi \delta(x)=0$

but  for  $x=0 $

$\lim\limits_{ x\to 0  } 2\pi \delta(x)=+\infty$

[image]

but the function is very special as Priyatham shew.

For $\epsilon>0$
$$ \int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon 2\pi \delta(x) \mathrm{d}x = 2\pi$$

Thus 
Finally we can get the important result for $\delta(x)$  function that

If $\epsilon>0$ then

$$\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon  \delta(x) \mathrm{d}x = 1$$

Note: The graphs were taken from [www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202sin%2810%5E100x%29/x%20)