# Let $a_k\gt 0$ and $a_0\gt \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ . Show that $\int_0^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \frac {\sin (a_k x)}{x} dx=\frac {\pi}{2}\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Let $a_k\gt 0$ and $a_0\gt \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ . Show that $$\int_0^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \frac {\sin (a_k x)}{x} dx=\frac {\pi}{2}\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$$

I saw this question on the internet somewhere a few days back and thought to give it a try. The question looks so absurd due to the arbitrary inputs in the sines and their products.

I tried giving it a shot using Laplace and Mellin transforms but realized they were turning to dead end. i also tried using a little complex analysis by writing sines in terms of $e$ but to no avail.

One method which seemed quite promising was the Feynman's technique because one peculiar thing about RHS is that it is independent of $a_0$ and also a point to note is the constraint on $a_0$( It is greater than sum of other $a_k$'s). Differentiating both sides w.r.t $a_0$ would give a $0$ on RHS while some integral on LHS which we need to prove is $0$. But couldn't much continue with this thought.

The place where I saw this question also had an answer but it used principle of induction which I pretty don't like much so it would be very much better if I could get methods without involving any type of induction.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Your equalitiy can be found for example within [this collocation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c737278h1674162_10010_rare_and_irresistible_integrals) of interesting integrals on AoPS. Moreover there is the proof using induction given [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1674162p10677683) which you refered to.

Comment: Looks like the old sinc-transforms-to-box-function argument (Fourier tfm that is).

Comment: As a different idea one may expand the fraction with $a_k$ followed by the subsitution $y=a_kx$ but I am not sure whether it is possible to exchange the order of integration and multiplication. For the case that it is in fact possible to do so one could use the well-known result concerning the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx~=~\frac{\pi}2$$ However I am not sure whether this argumentation would be valid or not since it does not consider the fact of the independancy of $a_0$ concerning the RHS.

Comment: @mrtaurho Oh,  Thanks for the links

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral#General_formula

Comment: [Some remarkable properties of $\displaystyle\mathrm{sinc}$ and related integrals](http://www.thebigquestions.com/borweinintegrals.pdf)  by D. Borwein and J. M. Borwein.

Answer (score 3):

Note from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/559194/how-to-prove-that-inverse-fourier-transform-of-1-is-delta-funstion) that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{a}^b\exp(\text{i}kx)\,f(k)\,\text{d}k\,\text{d}x=2\pi\,f(0)\,,\tag{*}$$
where $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a sufficiently well behaved function (e.g., $f$ is continuous), and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $a<0<b$.  Basically, this is what physicists tend to write: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\exp(\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}x=2\pi\,\delta(k)\,,$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta-distribution.

We also have
$$\frac{\sin(a_jx)}{x}=\frac{a_j}{2}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp(\text{i}a_jxk_j)\,\text{d}k_j$$
for $j=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.  The required integral is
$$I:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\prod_{j=0}^n\,\frac{\sin(a_jx)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\prod_{j=0}^n\,\frac{\sin(a_jx)}{x}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
That is,
$$I=\frac{\prod\limits_{r=0}^n\,a_r}{2^{n+2}}\,\prod_{j=1}^n\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}k_j\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\text{d}x\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}k_0\,\exp\Biggl(\text{i}\,x\,\left(a_0k_0+\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_jk_j\right)\Biggr)\,.$$
Thus,
$$I=\frac{\prod\limits_{r=0}^n\,a_r}{2^{n+2}}\,\prod_{j=1}^n\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}k_j\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\text{d}x\,\frac{1}{a_0}\,\int_{A}^{B}\,\text{d}\kappa\,\exp(\text{i}\,x\,\kappa)$$
where $$A:=-1+\frac{1}{a_0}\,\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_jk_j<0\,,$$ $$B:=+1+\frac{1}{a_0}\,\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_jk_j>0\,,$$
and $\kappa:=a_0k_0$.  (The results $A<0$ and $B>0$ follow from the hypothesis that $a_0>\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\,a_j$.)  Using (*), we get
$$I=\frac{\prod\limits_{r=1}^n\,a_r}{2^{n+2}}\,\,\prod_{j=1}^n\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}k_j\,(2\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\prod_{r=1}^n\,a_r\,.$$

---

Apparently, from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral#General_formula), in general case (where $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are positive real numbers with no extra conditions), we have
$$\text{vol}_n(V)=\frac{1}{n!\,\prod\limits_{r=1}^n\,a_r}\,\sum_{\gamma\in \{-1,+1\}^n}\,\epsilon_\gamma\,\beta_\gamma^n\,\text{sign}(\beta_\gamma)\,,\tag{#}$$
where
$\text{vol}_n$ is the $n$-dimensional volume, 
$$V:=\Biggl\{(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)\in[-1,+1]^n\,\Big|\,-a_0<\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_jk_j<+a_0\Biggr\}\,,$$
$$\epsilon_\gamma:=\gamma_1\gamma_2\cdots\gamma_n\,,$$
and $$\beta_\gamma:=a_0+\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_j\gamma_j\,.$$  Here, $\gamma_j$ is the $j$-coordinate of each $\gamma\in\{-1,+1\}^n$.  It would be interesting to prove (#), from which we have
$$\int_0^\infty\,\prod_{j=0}^n\,\frac{\sin(a_jx)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(\frac{1}{2^nn!}\,\sum_{\gamma\in \{-1,+1\}^n}\,\epsilon_\gamma\,\beta_\gamma^n\,\text{sign}(\beta_\gamma)\right)\,.$$
Note also that (#) is equivalent to $$\text{vol}_n(W)=\frac{1}{n!}\,\sum_{\gamma\in \{-1,+1\}^n}\,\epsilon_\gamma\,\beta_\gamma^n\,\text{sign}(\beta_\gamma)\,,$$
where $$W:=\Biggl\{(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\ldots,\kappa_n)\in\prod_{j=1}^n\,\left[-a_j,+a_j\right]\,\Big|\,-a_0<\sum_{j=1}^n\,\kappa_j<+a_0\Biggr\}\,.$$